# Update a dataframe by dataframes with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updates

I try to update a DataFrame

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]})
```

by another DataFrame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]}).
```

Now, my aim is to update `df1` by `df2` and overwrite all values (`NaN` values too) using

```
df1.update(df2)
```

In contrast with the common usage it's important to me to get the `NaN` values finally in `df1`.
But as far as I see the update returns

```
>>> df1
      A   B
0     1   9
1     2   6
2     3   11
3     4   8
```

Is there a way to get

```
>>> df1
    A    B
0   1    9
1   2    NaN
2   3    11
3   4    NaN
```

without building `df1` manually?

Comment: Your code work fine on my side

Comment: Do you perhaps truly have `NaN` values and not the string `'nan'`?

Comment: Anyway, I think you stumbled onto the solution. There's a default check in the source code that ignores `null` values from the update frame when `overwrite=True`, with no kwarg to overwrite this behavior. Just replace null values with some non-null dummy value (like `'nan'`), update, and replace the dummy value back to `np.NaN`

Comment: Is your expected output A column really 1,1,2,3?  Or should that be 1,2,3,4?

Answer (score 4):

I am late to the party but I was recently confronted to the same issue, *i.e.* trying to update a dataframe without ignoring NaN values like the Pandas built-in `update` method does.
For two dataframes sharing the same column names, a workaround would be to concatenate both dataframes and then remove duplicates, only keeping the last entry:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})

frames = [df1, df2]
df_concatenated = pd.concat(frames)
df1=df_concatenated.loc[~df_concatenated.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Depending on indexing, it might be necessary to sort the indices of the output dataframe:

```
df1=df1.sort_index()
```

---

To address you very specific example for which `df2` does not have a column A, you could run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})

frames = [df1, df2]
df_concatenated = pd.concat(frames)

df1['B']=df_concatenated.loc[~df_concatenated.index.duplicated(keep='last')]['B']
```

Answer (score 2):

A usable trick is to fill with a string like 'n/a', then replace 'n/a' with np.nan, and convert column type back to float

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, 'n/a', 11, 'n/a']})
df1.update(df2)
df1['B'] = df1['B'].replace({'n/a':np.nan})
df1['B'] = df1['B'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Some explanation about the type conversion: after the call to `replace`, the result is:

```
   A     B
0  1   9.0
1  2   NaN
2  3  11.0
3  4   NaN
```

This looks acceptable, but actually the type of column B has changed from float to object.

```
df1.dtypes
```

will give

```
A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

To set it back to float, you can use:

```
df1['B'] = df1['B'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And then, you shall have the expected result:

```
df1.dtypes
```

will give the expected type:

```
A      int64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works fine for me. You could perhaps use np.nan instead of 'nan'?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `[9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]`, not string `"nan".`

If there is no mandatory to use `update()` then do `df1.B = df2.B` instead, so that the new `df1.B` will contain `NaN`.

`DataFrame.update()` only updates non-NA values. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

Comment: In fact, the use of `'nan'` strings produces the same behavour as `np.nan` to me. The assignment seems to be the most obvious solution I missed out.

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1: Drop all affected columns

I achieved this by dropping the new columns and joining the data from the replacement DataFrame:

```py
df1 = df1.drop(columns=df2.columns).join(df2)
```

This tells Pandas to remove the columns from `df1` that you're about to recreate using the values from `df2`. Note that the column order changes since the new columns are appended to the end.

## Approach 2: Preserve column order

Loop over all columns in the replacement DataFrame, inserting affected columns in the target DataFrame in their original place after dropping the original. If the replacement DataFrame includes a column not in the target DataFrame, it will be appended to the end.

```py
for col in df2.columns:
    try:
        col_pos = list(df1.columns).index(col)
        df1.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
        df1.insert(col_pos, col, df2[col])
    except ValueError:
        df1[col] = df2[col]
```

## Caveat

With both of these approaches, if your indices do not match between `df1` and `df2`, the missing indices from `df2` will end up NaN in your output DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'A' : [5,6,7,8,9]})    # Note the additional row
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})
df1.update(df2)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    B     A
0   9.0   5
1   2.0   6
2   11.0  7
3   4.0   8
4   5.0   9
```

My version 1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'B' : [5,6,7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})
df1 = df1.drop(columns=df2.columns).join(df2)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1

    A   B
0   5   9.0
1   6   NaN
2   7   11.0
3   8   NaN
4   9   NaN
```

My version 2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5], 'B' : [5,6,7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})
for col in df2.columns:
    try:
        col_pos = list(df1.columns).index(col)
        df1.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
        df1.insert(col_pos, col, df2[col])
    except ValueError:
        df1[col] = df2[col]
```

Output:

```
>>> df1

    B     A
0   9.0   5
1   NaN   6
2   11.0  7
3   NaN   8
4   NaN   9
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas.DataFrame.update doesn't replace values by nan by default so to circumvent this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4], 'B' : [5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'B' : [9, np.nan, 11, np.nan]})

df2.replace(np.nan, 'NAN', inplace = True)
df1.update(df2)
df1.replace('NAN', np.nan,  inplace = True)
```